# MYSQL Query Just Year from Date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to alter the following query so that I can query by the year based off from a date/time field.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT lh.latitudedecimal AS vertreklat, lh.longitudedecimal AS vertreklong,      
 lh2.latitudedecimal AS aankomstlat, lh2.longitudedecimal AS aankomstlong, count(*) as    
 countroute, year('vertrekdatum2') AS jaar

 from tbl_vluchtgegevens vg

 left join tbl_luchthaven lh
 on vg.vertrekluchthaven = lh.luchthavenID

 left join tbl_luchthaven lh2
 on vg.aankomstluchthaven = lh2.luchthavenID

 WHERE year('vertrekdatum') = '$jID' 
 group by  lh.latitudedecimal, lh.longitudedecimal, lh2.latitudedecimal,   
 lh2.longitudedecimal
 HAVING COUNT(*)  = 1
```

I have the proper value showing up in the jaar column but when i test it, it comes up with 0 values, and there should be 15 showing up.

Note: $jID is coming from a value from php code on a different page.

I am assuming I just have the incorrect syntax for the WHERE portion of my clause.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure it's not your `HAVING COUNT(*)  = 1` clause that filters them out? If not, did you check the _exact_ value of `$jiD`? (Watch out for whitespace & the like).

Comment: Make shure vertrekdatum is a datetimefield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause is wrong.

```
 WHERE year('vertrekdatum') = '$jID'
```

the `vertrekdatum` is treated as a string.  It doesn't have a year component.  Try removing the single quotes:

```
 WHERE year(vertrekdatum) = $jID
```

*Only* use single quote for string and date constants.  The variable `$jID` should be an integer, so it doesn't need single quotes either.

The same applies in the `select` clause.

Comment: yes, this worked exactly as I was hoping. great to always keep learning. thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

assuming, that your code posted above is php, you probably have an error in where clause:

```
WHERE year('vertrekdatum') = "' . $jID . '"
```

should do the trick.
In your code $jID is a string, not a variable.

or

```
WHERE year('vertrekdatum') = ' . $jID . '
```

if it is an int value

edit my own answer:

```
WHERE year(vertrekdatum) = ' . $jID . '
```

as vertrekdatum is a fieldname, and not a string